# Truncate by the minimum of another DataFrame by columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Be the following python pandas DataFrame (df):

| age | money | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 300 | 10 |
| 8 | 200 | 20 |
| 20 | 1800 | 80 |
| 15 | 200 | 50 |

I want to extract the minimum value for each column:

| age | money | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 200 | 10 |

Given this other new dataframe (new_df):

| age | money | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | -100 | 15 |
| 10 | 100 | 50 |
| -2 | 1800 | -20 |
| 18 | -50 | 52 |

All values that are less than the minima of each column are set to the minimum value of the previous dataframe.

| age | money | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 200 | 15 |
| 10 | 200 | 50 |
| 8 | 1800 | 10 |
| 18 | 200 | 52 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) to get the min of `df`, then [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) to clip the values of `new_df`:

```
out = new_df.clip(lower=df.min(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   age  money  time
0   30    200    15
1   10    200    50
2    8   1800    10
3   18    200    52
```

Restricting to a subset of columns:

```
cols = ['age', 'time']
out = new_df[cols].clip(lower=df.min(), axis=1).combine_first(new_df)
```

output:

```
   age  money  time
0   30   -100    15
1   10    100    50
2    8   1800    10
3   18    -50    52
```

Comment: What if I only wanted to apply it to two of the three columns? Let's say ```age``` and ```time```.